locators are not visible in Eclipse even after importing Selenium JAR files
When I try to type driver.findelementbyID in Eclipse, when I click on Ctrl+SPACE for suggestions, it shows an empty box from the list of suggestion. I have attached the screen shot for reference:
Eclipse IDE screen capture
I tried clicking on Ctrl+SPACE the options are not displayed.  I would epxect all the selenium commands to be displayed in the suggestion box.

Are you sure that ChromeDriver has that method? I Do not know that class, but some documentation does not show that method --seems like there is a findElement(By locator) method instead - try that

What version of Eclipse are you using and how did you configure content assist ?

ITs working fine now. Thanks.

@user85421 Thanks for your comment its working fine now.

Looking at your screenshot I see you are instantiating a ChromeDriver() and for that we have to use findElement(By.<here you can click on CTRL+SPACE for suggestion>)
findElementById(), findElementByName(), findElementByXPath() are mostly used with the instances of RemoteWebDriver(), AndroidDriver() or IOSDriver().
